# Python iterating over a dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

for some reason I just can't iterate over a dictionary in Python. I've done it before but somehow I can't make it happen anymore. I feel like I'm missing something obvious although I don't know what exactly. I am currently learning Python at http://learnpythonthehardway.com/book Exercise 48. Using Nosetests and a given testcode I should then code the according code in the actual script to make the test work. Here is the code in the testfile:

```
from nose.tools import *
from ex48 import lexicon


def test_directions():
    assert_equal(lexicon.scan("north"), [('direction', 'north')])
    result = lexicon.scan("north south east")
    assert_equal(result, [('direction', 'north'),
                          ('direction', 'south'),
                          ('direction', 'east')])
```

So now I wrote this code to make the test work:

```
lex = { 'dir':'north', 'dir':'south', 'dir':'east', 'dir':'west', 
        'dir':'down', 'dir':'up', 'dir':'left', 'dir':'right', 
        'verb':'go', 'verb':'stop', 'verb':'kill', 'verb':'eat', 
        'stop':'the', 'stop':'in', 'stop':'of', 'stop':'from', 'stop':'at', 'stop':'it',
        'noun':'door', 'noun':'bear', 'noun':'princess', 'noun':'cabinet'}

def scan(word):
    for k in lex:
        if lex[k] == word:
            return (k, word)
    return None
```

`assert_equal()` just checks if both parameters are the same.
I am pretty sure this should work but anyway I changed it according to the Python documentation:

```
def scan(word):
    for k, v in dict.iteritems():
    if v == word:
        return (k, word)
    return None
```

Both ways just throw a `None` back at me and I just can't figure out why.

Comment: Dictionaries do not work like that - you can only have one value for e.g. the key `'dir'`. Also, please review your indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you build your lex dictionary is wrong. For example, you start by storing north for the key dir. Then you overwrite the key dir with south, and so on.
In the end, only one of those values is stored for dir. If you want multiple values in one key, combine them in a tuple:

`"dir" : ("north", "south", "east", "west")`

you'll need to adapt your other code to this change too, then, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now that you point it out I can see why it can't work. I guess it was just to obvious. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following would work, a list of acceptable words for each dictionary key is used:

```
lex = { 'dir': ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west', 'down', 'up', 'left', 'right'], 
        'verb': ['go', 'stop', 'kill', 'eat'], 
        'stop': ['the', 'in', 'of', 'from', 'at', 'it'],
        'noun': ['door', 'bear', 'princess', 'cabinet']}

def scan(word):
    for k, v in lex.items():
        if word.lower() in v:
            return (k, word)
    return None

print scan('north')
```

Which would print:

```
('dir', 'north')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It does now work. I can now see how my original approach was completley wrong. Thanks again!